# Does running an application in different zones cause slowness while accessin

Tags: mysql, latency, amazon-rds

Does the latency increase substantially if the applications are running on different zones. My rails app is running on **us-east-1a** and my MySQL RDS database is on **us-east-1d**. My application access seems to be slow, will this be a zone issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These zones are running in different data centers, so there will definitely be an increase in latency. Having said that, the Amazon EC2 user guide says:

> Amazon EC2 provides the ability to place instances in multiple
>   locations. Amazon EC2 locations are composed of Regions and
>   Availability Zones. Availability Zones are distinct locations that are
>   engineered to be insulated from failures in other Availability Zones
>   and provide inexpensive, low latency network connectivity to other
>   Availability Zones in the same Region.

([source](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/))

So the increase shouldn't be too substantial. I don't know what you mean by a "substantial" increase (is it a few ms? a few seconds?), but I guess the easiest way for you to figure out whether this is causing your latency issues would be to run your app and the MySQL server in the same zone, and see whether that brings the latency down again.

Comment: ~4-5 seconds for all queries

Comment: That seems excessive. I would put my money on that being something other than a zone issue.